# Insert multiple rows with default values without using union

Tags: mysql, sql

I use this query to insert multiple rows into my table `user`.

```
 insert into user 
  (select 'bbb', coalesce(max(subid),0)+1 from user where name = 'bbb')
  union
  (select 'ccc', coalesce(max(subid),0)+1 from user where name = 'ccc');
```

How can I achieve the same result in a single `select` query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite.  The problem is what happens when the names are not in the table.  You can do this:

```
insert into user(name, subid)
    select n.name, coalesce(max(u.subid), 1)
    from (select 'bbb' as name union all select 'ccc') n left join
         user u
         on u.name = n.name
    group by u.name;
```

It still has a `union (all)` for constructing the names, but the calculation of `subid` is only expressed once.

When using `insert` it is a good idea to list the columns explicitly.